# Visual Studio Code and version completion in bower.json

Tags: visual-studio-2015, bower, intellisense, visual-studio-code

When I try to add a dependency in bower.json, intellisense only proposes me the choice "latest" when I type the version number of the desired package (any package, like bootstrap for instance). Is VSCode badly configured?

Comment: Just checked in VS2015. I get the same behaviour, except that this one shows the exact version number instead of the word "latest". No way to autocomplete other version numbers...

Comment: I am working with VSC on a Mac. Have the same issue. Also, the 'latest' hint appears only when I start typing latest without the quotes.